# SimpleWebRtc - latest-v2.js stoped working

Tags: simplewebrtc

i'm using SimpleWebRtc on my webistes, but about week ago all sites with video peer (video chat) stoped working. I can see that my scripts try to include this file: "https://simplewebrtc.com/latest-v2.js", but it's not active - so video chat is not working.

My question is - maybe somebody have this file or someone knows where i can download it?

Regards,
Luke

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can download it from Github repo on tag 2.2.3 here is [the raw file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC/2.2.3/latest-v2.js).